# how to apply style to Pandas specific cell with given row name and column name?

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas object that I wants to highlight changed cells. I can get the specific row index and the column name, how to achieve this target?

I have this code, but it is checking cell value that incorrect cells will be highlighted as well.

```
dn.applymap(lambda v: "color: red;" if v == df_new.loc[AccountId, "AccountStatus"] else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
out = dn.style.applymap(lambda v: "color: red;" if v == dn.loc[AccountId, "AccountStatus"] else "")
```